# Plot factorial function in TikZ datavisualization

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs, pgfkeys, tikz-datavisualization

I'm trying to replicate [this graph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/487278/6505634) following the tips in [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/570158/127473) with [TikZ datavisualization package](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) (see Part VI).

[**edit**] related question: [How to make a figure showing growth of functions but with scaled y-axis?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233586)

This is the desired output:

[image: desired output]

**bonus**: it would be wonderful if it would be possible to reproduce [this graph](https://www.bigocheatsheet.com/) adding colored regions.

This is my output:

[image: actual output]

I have two problems that I don't know how to resolve:

1. I have to manually compute the values at which to stop the `x` of the functions `x^2`, `2^n`, `x!` because otherwise they will overflow from the top edge;
2. I don't know how to invoke the `Gamma` function to plot the factorial on real numbers [as suggested here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/570171/127473), also I'm typesetting this document on Windows and my colleagues are on linux, so the solution has to be cross-platform (without using `gnuplot`).

This is what I've done so far:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization.formats.functions}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd, use comma, set thousands separator={\,}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization [scientific axes=inner ticks,
                    style sheet=strong colors,
                    x axis={label={\textbf{\textsf{Elements}}}, length=8cm, min value=0, max value=100},
                    y axis={label={\textbf{\textsf{Operations}}}, length=5cm, min value=0, max value=2500},
                    data/format=function,
                    visualize as smooth line/.list={direct, logarithmic, linear, nlogarithmic, quadratic, exponential, factorial},
                    direct={label in legend={text=$\mathcal{O}(1)$}},
                    logarithmic={label in legend={text=$\mathcal{O}(\log n)$}},
                    linear={label in legend={text=$\mathcal{O}(n)$}},
                    nlogarithmic={label in legend={text=$\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$}},
                    quadratic={label in legend={text=$\mathcal{O}(n^2)$}},
                    exponential={label in legend={text=$\mathcal{O}(2^n)$}},
                    factorial={label in legend={text=$\mathcal{O}(n!)$}},
                    ]
data [set=direct] {
    var x : interval [0:100];
    func y = 1;
}
data [set=logarithmic] {
    var x : interval [1:100];
    func y = ln(\value x);
}
data [set=linear] {
    var x : interval [0:100];
    func y = \value x;
}
data [set=nlogarithmic] {
    var x : interval [1:100];
    func y = (\value x) * ln(\value x);
}
data [set=quadratic] {
    var x : interval [0:50];
    func y = \value x^2;
}
data [set=exponential] {
    var x : interval [0:11];
    func y = 2^(\value x);
}
data [set=factorial] {
    var x : interval [0:7];
    func y = factorial(\value x);
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For your gamma function this answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371255/plot-a-factorial-function) might help. Additionally, you can use `restrict y to domain=ymin:ymax` in the `axis` environment to set the borders of your plot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ditched TikZ datavisualization and I installed gnuplot on windows [from here](http://www.gnuplot.info/download.html).

Then I arranged [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/570158/127473) for my needs.

The result is the following

[image]

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\definecolor{direct}{HTML}{004518}
\definecolor{logarithmic}{HTML}{00A54F}
\definecolor{linear}{HTML}{C9DA2A}
\definecolor{nlogarithmic}{HTML}{FFC30D}
\definecolor{squared}{HTML}{F8931D}
\definecolor{cubed}{HTML}{F36523}
\definecolor{factorial}{HTML}{ED1B24}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{samples = 200}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\Omicron}{\mathcal{O}}

% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }
% arara: gnuplot: { input: [ bigO-complexity.pgf-plot.gnuplot ] }
% arara: clean: { extensions: [aux, log, pgf-plot.gnuplot, pgf-plot.table] }
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mystyle/.style={above, style = {font=\large}}
]
    \begin{axis}[
        % grid = major,
        clip = true, ticks = none,
        width = 15cm, height = 10cm,
        enlargelimits = false,
        scale only axis = true,
        every axis plot/.append style = {very thick},
        axis line style = ultra thick,
        clip mode = individual,
        domain = 0:10,
        restrict y to domain=0:10,
        restrict x to domain=0:10,
        axis x line = left, axis y line = left,
        xmin = 0, xmax = 11,
        ymin = 0, ymax = 11,
        xlabel = {Elements}, ylabel = {Operations},
        label style = {font=\large\bfseries\sffamily},
        xlabel style = {at={(axis description cs:0.5,-0.05)}, anchor=south},
        ylabel style = {at={(axis description cs:0.05,0.5)}, anchor=south},
    ]
    \addplot[color=direct]       {1}                 node[mystyle]{\(\Omicron(1)\)};
    \addplot[color=logarithmic]  {log2 x}            node[mystyle]{\(\Omicron(\log n)\)};
    \addplot[color=linear]       {x}                 node[mystyle]{\(\Omicron(n)\)};
    \addplot[color=squared]      {x^2}               node[mystyle]{\(\Omicron(n^2)\)};
    \addplot[color=nlogarithmic] {x*(log2 x)}        node[mystyle]{\(\Omicron(n\log n)\)};
    \addplot[color=cubed]        {x^3}               node[mystyle]{\(\Omicron(n^3)\)};
    \addplot[color=factorial]    gnuplot{gamma(x+1)} node[mystyle, yshift=0.6cm]{\(\Omicron(n!)\)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just as in the question/answer you refer to, you have the problem that the small interval is not suitable to show the fast growth of `n!` . I would think that the purpose for such a graph is to show non-technical people different growths and not leave them guessing weather `n!` or `n^3` is growing faster.

Comment: I have read the comment on the other question and I agree with you but I don't find a range that satisfies me, however I think the colors can help. @hpekristiansen Could you suggest a solution?

Comment: The solution is simple - enlarge the domain. See you own very first picture as an example - it perfectly shows the different growths with light blue `n!` as a clear winner. Your colors and no numbers are better.